# Unable to install language-bable in atom 1.18.0

Tags: ubuntu

Here is what I am getting when tried to install.

Installing “language-babel@2.68.0” failed.Hide output…

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-59-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/nits-50/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/nits-50/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-11773-7444-h2ynxl.fnq37n9udi/package.tgz" "--runtime=electron" "--target=1.3.15" "--arch=x64" "--global-style"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file /home/nits-50/.atom/.apm/core-js/2.4.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: /home/nits-50/.atom/.apm/core-js/2.4.1/package/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-11773-7444-1ijqiaq.s2apkwewmi/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got the solution (it is strange):

I found that /home/nits-50/.atom/.apm/core-js/2.4.1/package/package.json contained nothing .. so it was causing json parse error.

I simply deleted this file. and It worked.